# Why does Gson add slashes to String

Tags: java, servlets, gson

I implemented a simple HttpServlet. The servlet takes requests and calls a third party API to get the data, and then sends data back in response. However, in the response, JSON adds too many slashes.

Does anyone know why?
Below is my code.

```
public class InstitutionServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String apiUrl = "https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4&q=" + city;
        String data = getInstitutions(apiUrl);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        gson.toJson(data, pw);
    }

    //Get institutions data from API url.
    private String getInstitutions(String apiUrl) {
        StringBuilder institutions = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(apiUrl);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                institutions.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return institutions.toString();
    }
}
```

Original data from the API https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4&q=whatever:

```
{
    "help": "https://inventory.data.gov/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search",
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "resource_id": "38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4",
        "q": "whatever",
        "records": [],
        "_links": {
            "start": "/api/action/datastore_search?q=whatever&resource_id=38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4",
            "next": "/api/action/datastore_search?q=whatever&offset=100&resource_id=38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4"
        }
    }
}
```

Data in servlet response `http://localhost:8080/getInstitutions?city=wahtever`:

```
"{\"help\": 
  \"https://inventory.data.gov/api/3/action/help_show?name\u003ddatastore_search\", 
  \"success\": true, 
  \"result\": {
    \"resource_id\": \"38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4\", 
    \"q\": \"wahtever\", 
    \"records\": [], 
    \"_links\": {
      \"start\": \"/api/action/datastore_search?q\u003dwahtever\u0026resource_id\u003d38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4\", 
      \"next\": \"/api/action/datastore_search?q\u003dwahtever\u0026offset\u003d100\u0026resource_id\u003d38625c3d-5388-4c16-a30f-d105432553a4\"
    }
  }
}\n"
```

Comment: Your JSON is being escaped as a regular Java string

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, you have any idea why `gson.toJson(data, pw)` does not work? Thanks.

Comment: Just write `data` to the print writer without Gson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gson.toJson(data, pw)` is taking the string `data` and converting it to JSON, so to do that, it'll escape all characters it needs to in order to create a valid JSON string.

It's not really clear why you need Gson for this scenario, you should be able to write out `data` to the `PrintWriter` directly  assuming that the other function there is already returning a string in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I can write data directly to the print. I use gson because I will convert the string to json object and remove some nodes from the json object.

Comment: You've essentially done the equivalent to javascript  `JSON.stringify` in your question